# How to connect dockerized couchbase server from dockerized spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, couchbase

I create a simple spring boot and couchbase app and I want to dockerized it.

I create Dockerfile for Spring Boot:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-slim AS build
RUN mkdir -p /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY pom.xml /workspace
COPY src /workspace/src
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:8
COPY --from=build /workspace/target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

and my couchbase's dockerfile:

```
FROM couchbase

RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
COPY configure-server.sh /opt/couchbase
RUN chmod +x /opt/couchbase/configure-server.sh

CMD ["/opt/couchbase/configure-server.sh"]
```

And Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  couchbase:
    build: ./couchbase
    container_name: couchbase
    volumes:
      - ~/couchbase/node1:/opt/couchbase/var
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
      - 8092:8092
      - 8093:8093
      - 11210:11210

  todo_server:
    build: ./todo-backend
    container_name: todo_server
    depends_on:
      - couchbase
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

If I try to `docker-compose up couchbase` and run spring boot locally they work together. But When I try to use `docker-compose up`, Spring App can not connect to couchbase server.

I guess this is caused by localhost

My Couchbase Config on Spring

```java
@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfiguration extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {
    @Override
    public String getConnectionString() {
        return "couchbase://127.0.0.1";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserName() {
        return "Administrator";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return "password";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBucketName() {
        return "default";
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean autoIndexCreation() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think I have to change this

```java
 public String getConnectionString() {
        return "couchbase://127.0.0.1";
    }
```

I tried only `couchbase` and `couchbase://couchbase` but it doesn't work.

Errors on console:

```
com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:11210
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
        at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124) ~[core-io-2.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:243) ~[core-io-2.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:672) ~[core-io-2.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:649) ~[core-io-2.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:529) ~[core-io-2.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:465) ~[core-io-2.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[core-io-2.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[core-io-2.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[core-io-2.0.8.jar:na]
        at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[core-io-2.0.8.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the network environment here.  From the point of view of the `todo_server` container, `localhost` is itself, not another container or the physical host.  You should be able to use the other Compose service name `couchbase` as a host name.

Comment: What error do you get if you use "couchbase" as the connection string?

Comment: I solved this problem, I changed localhost part and change docker-compose file, I'll share new docker-compose on comment

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by doing the following.

My new Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    build: ./couchbase
    container_name: todo-couchbase
    volumes:
      - ~/couchbase/node1:/opt/couchbase/var
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
      - 8092:8092
      - 8093:8093
      - 11210:11210
    networks:
      - my_network
  todo_server:
    build: ./todo-backend
    container_name: todo-backend
    environment:
      COUCHBASE_HOST: db
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

and I changed connection string

```java
 public String getConnectionString() {
        return "db";
    }
```